# Application loader error message (iPhone)

Tags: iphone

Application loader is giving me this error when uploading an app to the AppStore:

```
Missing argument for option: p
```

What could it be?

Comment: seems like a bug. Did you try the built-in upload function in Xcode?

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. Post your tip as an answer if you want to receive the bounty.

Comment: How is the default built-in upload in XCode works? Where is that option provided?

Comment: @Anil Sivadas. Build and archive your app then open the Organizer, Archives and then click on submit application to iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug in the APplication Loader. Be sure you have the very latest version (Apple does update it periodically).

It is very possible that the Application Loadeer does not deal well with 'special' characters in usernames and passwords. I've read about a case where people ran into similar issues where the password contained a single or double quote. (`'`, `"`)